# Running two functions simultaneously c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to reduce computation time. I am trying to run two functions simultaneously and use the return value from whichever function exited first.

Imagine I had these two functions. (These aren't my actual functions they are just useful simple representations of what my functions look like)

```
int countUp (int n){

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

if( i == n ) return i; 

}

return -1;
}

int countDown (int n){

for(int i = 200; i > 0; i--){

if( i == n ) return i; 

}
return -1;
}
```

In main, how would I run both of them simultaneously and get the return value of whichever one exited first?

Comment: Is this `C`, `C++` or `C#`? Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Why not Perl, Erlang or Scheme?

Comment: Is threading a possibility in your case? possibly pthreads?

Comment: There is no guarantee that multiple threads or tasks will run simultaneously.  The OS is in charge of delegating CPU cores and blocks of time.  You could have many threads and they could all possible be run on the same CPU core, not simultaneously.  I suggest you look into using GPU cores.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What if there is a one-to-one? One user thread per one kernel thread. Which is what I believe windows does. They just have a pool of maximum threads that can be created.

Comment: You will have to implement some kind of signal from the threads when they finish, to signal the main thread.  Or you could poll some kind of shared variable to determine which thread finished first.  For example, the first thread could run to completion, then the second thread started.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI:  Windows does not perform a 1:1.  I know that there are interrupts happening and other drivers being executed while any given program is running.  You will have to investigate the Windows API to find a method for preventing task switching.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews gotcha thanks. Well I read in my Operating Systems book that Windows is 1:1, but we all know how garbage education is for CS....

Comment: Getting the "first result that's ready" is not trivial to implement, since you'll need some cross-thread communications channel. You could perhaps rig something up with a mutex and a condition variable. Then if you want to "cancel" the other thread prematurely, that's a whole different story.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: Kernel threads are something completely different and not relevant here.

Comment: For c++, use a `std::condition_variable` and a couple of `std::thread`s and a way to signal the result (`std::atomic<int>` maybe, or a plain int with a `std::mutex`)

Comment: I'm not sure why all the downvotes for this question. Its absolutely non-trivial (because of the 1st to finish condition). +1 condition variable. A queue  suitable for communication between threads also solves this (which should usually have a condition variable internally in order to wake the listener when an items is pushed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a `mutex` and `condition_variable` to set up a conversation between `countUp`, `countDown`, and `main`:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

int
countUp(int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if( i == n )
            return i; 
    }
    return -1;
}

int
countDown(int n)
{
    for(int i = 200; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if( i == n )
            return i; 
    }
    return -1;
}

int
main()
{
    int result;
    constexpr int N = 200;
    std::thread t1{[&result, N]
                   {
                       int t = countUp(N);
                       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
                       result = t;
                       ready = true;
                       cv.notify_one();
                   }};
    std::thread t2{[&result, N]
                   {
                       int t = countDown(N);
                       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
                       result = t;
                       ready = true;
                       cv.notify_one();
                   }};
    {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    while (!ready)
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Here I've used lambdas just so I don't intrusively modify `countUp` and `countDown`.  If it is ok to modify these functions you could move the signaling directly into them and avoid the lambdas.

I've chosen to have `main` join with the threads after printing out the result to avoid the possibility that `mut` and `cv` get accessed by one of the threads after they are destructed by `main`'s atexit chain.  If you can prove that such access won't happen, then you could `.detach()` the threads instead of `.join()`, and thus eliminate the need for `main` to wait for the slower `thread` to finish.  This could be done (for example) by having `countUp`, `countDown` and `main` share ownership of the mutex and condition_variable with a `shared_ptr`.

If it were somehow important to your logic, you could even prevent the slower thread from updating the result with:

```
                   if (!ready)
                       result = t;
```

Answer (score 1):

possible C++11 solution using futures.

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds

int countUp (int n) {
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if( i == n ) return i; 
}
return -1;
}

int countDown (int n){
for(int i = 200; i > 0; i--){
if( i == n )
    return i; 
}
return -1;
}

int main ()
{
  std::future<int> futUp = std::async (std::launch::async, countUp, 50); 
  std::future<int> futDown = std::async (std::launch::async, countDown, 50); 

  std::chrono::microseconds span (1); // or even std::chrono::nanoseconds for better accuracy
  do
  {
    if (futUp.wait_for(span) != std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "CountUp finished first with result = " << futUp.get() << std::endl;
        break;   
    }
    if (futDown.wait_for(span) != std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "CountDown finished first with result = " << futDown.get() << std::endl;
        break;   
    }
  } while (true);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the 'first one to finish'

Comment: what about now ? it's not 100% perfect but it's better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use 2 computers and run one function in each computer.
Solution 2: Use this or something like...

```
int function( int n )
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  if (i <= 100) {
    if( i == n)
      return i;
  }
  else {
    if(200 - i == n)
      return 200 -i;
  }    
 }

  return -1;
}
```